# Nginx 403 Forbidden

Tags: nginx, wordpress, http-status-code-403

after trying three times in other StackExchange Forums, I hope I'm getting an answer here.

I switched my wordpress webserver from apache2 to nginx (please note that I want to use the existing wordpress instance) and now I just can't connect to it. Sometimes I get `connection refused` and if that's not the case I get `403: Forbidden`.

What is the best solution to fix that problem?
My nginx.conf:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    error_log  /var/log/nginx_error.log error;
    access_log  /var/log/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # SSL
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # no sslv3 (poodle etc.)
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Gzip Settings
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/javascript application/$

    fastcgi_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/cache/fcgi levels=1:2 keys_zone=microca$


    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

My wordpress.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name snapecraft.ddns.net;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/vhost1.access.log;
   error_log             /var/log/nginx/vhost1.error.log;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you also share your relevant old Apache configuration?

Comment: Please find and provide lines with "403 error" from your nginx access/error logs.

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: Somehow the error log is empty/there are only old, already fixed errors in there. Are my log settings OK?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to list directory contents use `autoindex` on; like:

```
location /somedir {
       autoindex on;
}
```

sudo nginx -s reload

Comment: Not that what I want to do, but I'll give it a try. Is it possible to set the dir to the root?